# How to update cell values of Sheet2 based on dropdown option chosen on Sheet1?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, dropdown, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am creating a spreadsheet for a future wedding and populating Sheet1 with names (Column A), RSVPs (Column B), and Column C as dropdown menus with options "Yes" or "No" if the person needs a room booked for them.

In my Sheet2 I want to populate Column A with the names of the people, and Column B with the # of people they RSVP'd if the chose the option of "Yes" in Sheet1 for needing a room booked So I can keep track of who needs rooms booked and for how many people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simple `QUERY` to get your desired output:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:C, "select A, B where C = 'Yes'", 0)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try (in sheet 2, cell A1)

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:B, Sheet1!C:C="Yes")
```

and see if that works?